# I can not connect to the port

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I get a window that says ... waiting for tor to start ... and until it gives me an error that says that it is impossible to connect tor port, why does this happen to me? 
Weeks ago could connect without problems, I do not understand because now I have problems connecting to the port itself

Comment: anti-virus or firewalls commonly cause issues like this.

Comment: Is quite rare because I used it well with the antivirus and the firewall, and suddenly it stopped working, I have excluded antivirus anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From your Terminal, run:

`service tor stop
service tor start
service tor status`

you should see an output along the lines of:

```
 tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
 (multi-instance-master)    Loaded: loaded
 (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset:        
 disabled)    
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-08-01 00:44:46
 UTC; 2h 43min ago   Process: 3603 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited,
 status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 3603 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

if there's any errors in this output, you should be able to troubleshoot the service in a bit more detail, if it *is* an issue with the service.

Also why not take a look at the following repository TorStat, here:

```
https://github.com/rootlabs/TorStat
```

Tor stat essentially allows you to overlay your Tor connection with proxychains, and will give you an output directly showing which of your ports are connected to the service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tor process is unable to start properly. You have to find your tor log file. There must be a message about tor startup and every errors during startup will be there. Tor produce many verbose helpful messages, especially when something goes wrong.

Try to find errors in the log file. Let us see them.